# How to add open and close quotes if A string has spaces

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write an If then statement to see if a string has a space in it.  If it does, I want it to put an " and " around the variable.  Below is my current code:

```
If ColumnText.Contains(" ") Then
                        MsgBox(""" & ColumnText & """)
                    End If
                Next
```

But it's seeing quoting everything...  Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the content of `ColumnText`? Also, did you mean `MsgBox("""" & ColumnText & """")` ? (notice 4 quote symbols instead of 3).

Comment: This worked, I'll accept your answer, but i'm confused... why """"  I would think that would make it "" Value ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly escape a double quote inside VB's double quoted string literal, you need to double it (no pun intended). This means an empty string `""`. When you squeeze a quote in it, you get 4 quotes `""""`, and this really means just one double quote literal.

You should be using:

```
MsgBox("""" & ColumnText & """")
```

Instead of:

```
MsgBox(""" & ColumnText & """)
```

Another thing - notice how the syntax parser highlights your line when it has 3 quotes. In this case `& ColumnText &` is part of the literal, instead of being an inline variable.

Reference:

- [String literals @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711651%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: MsgBox isn't supported anymore, use MessageBox.Show instead, just a suggestion...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: It's perfectly supported actually (not showing as deprecated/obsolete and such), but I get your point. I too prefer MessageBox.Show, but in this case problem was unrelated to it. Could have been some other function with a string parameter, the answer would still stand as is.

Comment: I agree have a read here about why to use MessageBox over MsgBox... http://www.gringod.com/2005/01/26/vbnet-msgbox-or-messageboxshow/

Answer (score 1):

Using quote literals makes for hard to read code and as seen here, can easily lead to errors.  I find it much easier to use (and read) `String.Format` and isolate things you want to call out differently.  For instance:

```
msg = String.Format("There is a problem with [{0}]", columnText)
```

The result: `There is a problem with [foobar]`

If you really like quotes, or need for something else like a command line argument, you can still make the code more legible this way:

```
Const quote As String =  """"
' or
Private quote = Convert.ToChar(34)      ' 34 is the code for the quote char
'...
msg = String.Format("There is a problem with {0}{1}{0}", quote, columnText)
```

The result: `There is a problem with "foobar"`  In cases where there are multiple things to wrap with quotes, you just repeat `{0}` for each as shown.

Comment: +1. Although I feel like declaring a variable `doubleQuote = """"` would be much easier to explain than `Chr(34)` (and the fact there exists an ASCII table).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
If ColumnText.Contains(" ") Then
                    MsgBox(Chr(34) & ColumnText & Chr(34))
                End If
            Next
```