# Remove single quote (") from string and replace double quotes ("") with single quotes (") in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string similar to this one in VB.NET:

```
Dim str as String = """This is an """"example"""" string"""
```

Which looks like this in plaintext: `"This is an ""example"" string"`

What I want to do is remove the single quotes from this value and replace the double quotes with single quotes: `This is an "example" string`

I don't see a way of doing this that wouldn't also remove the double quotes.

Comment: `str = String.Format("This is an {0}example{0} string", Convert.ToChar(34))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add open and close quotes if A string has spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145046/how-to-add-open-and-close-quotes-if-a-string-has-spaces)