# How can I read a path with space in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I tried to use process.start, it work's but when my path got a folder with space, process.start can't read it.

```
Process.Start("powershell", """c:\sp ace\test.ps1""")
process.start("powershell", "\""c:\\sp ace\\test.ps1""")
...
```

And so on, I think I read every topics but it fails all the time. 
Maybe there is something special with `$`Process.start`$` idk i'm lost

Thx for any help

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: yep my error is like : "C:\sp" is not a ps1 file 
he can't read after the space.  

Exactly : The term 'c:\sp' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.

Comment: `Process.Start("c:\sp ace\test.ps1")` the path to the "to be executed"-file should be enough

Comment: Process.Start("c:\sp ace\test.ps1") open test.ps1 with an editor :/

Comment: so If you manually open the file, does it open in the editor as well?

Comment: yes with the same editor. The problem is if i run my application on another PC that does not open by default with powershell there will be the same bug. that's why i want tu use    Process.start([string], [string])

Comment: You can do this also with a shortcut-file (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "& ""C:\sp ace\test.ps1"""

Comment: ok .. with note editor default process.start("c:\sp ace\test.ps1") works but with powershell default didn't. i think it's a powershell issue, i looking for that

Comment: ("powershell", "& ""c:\sp ace\test.ps1""") doesn't work :/

Comment: hohohohoh Process.start("powershell", "c:\sp` ace\test.ps1") wooooorks :D i'm so happy thx a lot guys !! have a good day :D love u so mutch :) (if u still here how should i do to wait the end of process.start to continue the vb code ? )

Comment: dim proc as process -- proc = process.start([string],[string]) -- proc.waitforexit() i'm done with this ! have a good night :)

Comment: Good Catch! You can post your answer to this question ;)

Comment: [This answer might be helpful too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24145158/1070452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process.start("powershell", "c:\sp` ace\test.ps1")
```

work's

just in case :

```
dim proc as process -- 
proc = process.start([string],[string]) -- 
proc.waitforexit()
```